# Android Application: Got Internet Connection

Tags: android

How can I check got a successful internet connect (Wifi/3G/whatever else) I already display an error to the user if they don't have Wifi connection but how can I make sure then that the user does got 3G connection if they wish to connect to use the application without the Wifi connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see if the phone is connected to the network, you could try: `ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo()` and then for each network adapter check `networkinfo.getState()`.  That should tell you whether it's connected or not.  However, I'm not sure if there's a way to specifically check for 3G.